# Freezing testing to stable

Tags: debian

I'm currently tracking the "testing" release of Debian because testing is now converging to stable. Once "testing" will be promoted to "stable" (later this year I guess), I'd like to turn my testing version to stable. I guess that once the next Debian will be released, stable and testing will be more ore less the same for a few days. Other questions are always about migrating from testing back to an old stable. For me it'll to to move from testing to a not-quite-old stable. Is this the same procedure as in the other questions, or is there a better way ?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to track "stretch" instead of "testing".